# How to compare two apache arrow tables for equality ignoring order in C++?

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

In unit tests, I want to compare actual and expected `arrow::Table`s but ignoring order because the ordering is randomized by concurrency in the system under test.

I'd like to compare two tables for equality like `table1.Equals(table2)` but ignoring row order.

Alternatively, how can I sort the tables by all columns so I can then compare them?

Comment: I'm guessing the tables don't include any unique ID column you can sort on by itself?

Comment: I could possibly include a unique ID if it would help. Would it?

Comment: Possibly.  If both arrow tables share the same set of unique IDs then you only need to sort on that one column not multiple columns.  And for comparisons you only need to compare the unique ID columns for each table not all columns.  That would be a field like an invoice ID since there should never be 2 invoices with the same ID.  Something like a customer ID won't work if your tables can include for example multiple invoices from one customer ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort a table on all columns (this is how arrow-C++ and pyarrow compare tables, ignoring order, internally):

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.compute as pc

table = ...
sort_keys = [(name, 'ascending') for name in table.column_names]
sort_indices = pc.sort_indices(table, sort_keys)
sorted_table = pc.take(table, sort_indices)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try. Any chance you can point me at an example in C++?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/apache-arrow-12.0.1/cpp/src/arrow/acero/test_util_internal.cc#L461-L473